# One test error from many sample tests in CodeWar

Tags: python-3.x, nlp-question-answering

I've written a code for this question and the result shows one failure after running test samples on it. I've no idea what is wrong with my code when majority of the sample tests could run successfully except for one. The function of the program is to determine if the ticket clerk would be able to return the change to the customer given that he has no change at the start. The price of the movie ticket is 25 dollars. For instance, an array of the handed dollars notes is as followed [25,50], he would be able to return the change when the array finishes running since he would receive a 25 dollars note at the start and the he would be able to return the 25 dollars note to the 2nd customer when he handed a 50 dollars note. However, if this array is given [25,100], the program would print "NO" since he would not have enough change for the 100 dollars note. 
By the way, this is for Python3++.

```
def tickets(people):
   co25=0
   co50=0
   co100=0
   collect=0
   for i in people:
      if(i==25):    
         co25+=1
      elif(i==50):
         co50+=1
         if(co25>=1):
             co25=co25-1
         else:
             collect+=1
      elif(i==100):
          co100+=1
          if(co25>=1 and co50>=1):
              co25=co25-1
              co50=co50-1
           else:
              collect+=1
      else:
          break;
   if(collect>0):
        return("NO")
    else:
        return ("YES")
```

[image: Question and result]

Comment: You did not tell us what input make your test failure?

Comment: The website doesn't reveal the input value..

Comment: @user234568 - are you able to solve it or not?  I've tried it and may offer some idea.